# regex pattern optimization

Tags: regex, optimization

I have the following patterns and grouping application which I am refactoring in one. The following will be placed in a xml file and read into a regex engine:

```
 regexpattern="http://cars.mysite.com(.*)" application="http://www.mysite.com$1"

  regexpattern="http://ww.mysite.com(.*)" application="http://www.mysite.com$1 

    regexpattern="http://(bikes\.|new\.|)mysite.com/(.*)" application="http://www.mysite.com/$2"
```

combined into this:

```
regexpattern="http://(cars\.|ww\.|bikes\.|new\.|)mysite.com(|/)(.*)"  application="http://www.mysite.com/$3"
```

Is this the best I could do, can it be done better? I am new to this. Thanks.

Comment: Optimize for what? Correctness? Runtime speed? Readability? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have a missing backslash:

```
http://(cars\.|ww\.|bikes\.|new\.|)mysite\.com(|/)(.*)
                                         ^
```

2. Instead of `(|/)` you can use `/?`:

```
http://(cars\.|ww\.|bikes\.|new\.|)mysite\.com/?(.*)
                                              ^^
```

3. Making the slash optional means that it accepts things like `mysite.com.co.uk` which is probably not what you want.

4. Another minor change is to write `\.` only once:

```
http://((cars|ww|bikes|new)\.)?mysite\.com/?(.*)
                           ^^
```

Answer (score 0):

A full regex refactor looks something like :

`http://((?:(?:car|bike)s|(?:w|ne)w)\.)?mysite\.com/?.*`